# System.IO.Compression.FileSystem not found with VS 2010 Express 4.5.50938

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 Express 4.5.50938, but when I go to add a reference there is no System.IO.Compression.FileSystem under .NET tab, but I found a 4.0 version under the Recent Tab.  When program runs I receive:

```
Warning 1   Reference to type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll', but it could not be found  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll Zip_Copy_To_Public
```

Do I copy the dll into this directory?

Comment: You are using types that are only available in .NET 4.5.  Yet you target 4.0, your program is going to fall over and die when it actually runs on a machine that only has 4.0 installed.  And no, picking reference assemblies by hand from c:\windows\microsoft.net is **never** correct.  Very little point to get stuck on an old version of free software btw.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 does not support .NET 4.5, but VS 2012 onwards does.
For ZIP archive support, look at [this project on codeplex](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/).

Or, alternatively, you can look at the [VS 2013 Express products](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).

Comment: If I go to 'About' under Help it lists my .NET as version 4.5.50938.

Comment: @KFP - That may be the version that is installed but that is not the version that was installed with VS2010.  VS2010 cannot target v4.5.

Comment: @KFP the capability simply isn't built into the express version of 2010. Have you looked at the codeplex project? If you're not willing to install a fresh version of VSx, that might solve your problems.